# does max_fail and fail_timeout parameters are supported in Nginx or is it available only for Nginx Plus?

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy

I have the application in which the least_conn is used and the max_fails=5 with fail_timeout=300seconds.
Does above mentioned parameters are part of nginx or nginx plus?
What is the relevance of the above mentioned parameters w.r.t to least_conn or is this is used in nginx or nginx plus.

Answer (score 0):

These parameters are used as part of the open source version.  These are associated with passive health checks.  That is stated here: https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/load-balancer/http-health-check/#passive-health-checks

Nginx plus offers active health checks that verifies the state of the server regardless of traffic.